# Is there any way to make both unsorted and sorted linked list by only adding single struct instance

Tags: c++

```
void addTutorIntoBeginning(int TID, std::string tutorName, std::string dateJoined, double hourlyRate, std::string phone, std::string address, std::string tuitionCode, std::string subjCode, double rating)
{
    tutor* newTutor = createTutor(TID, tutorName, dateJoined, hourlyRate, phone, address, tuitionCode, subjCode, rating);

    //check if list is empty
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newTutor;
        tail = newTutor;
        size++;
    }

    else
    {
        newTutor->next = head;
        head->prev = newTutor;
        head = newTutor;
        size++;
    }
}
```

the adding function is for unsorted list. What if the unsorted list has gone through sorted process, is it possible to revert back the sorted list to the unsorted list (since the next and prev pointers are pointed to different instance after sorted) without creating 2 different lists which that one is an unsorted list and another is a sorted list that need to create two newTutor instances at the same time when performing the adding function.

Or the best way is to actually create two different list instead?

Sorry if the wording is bad.

Comment: Why you need to sort and revert the list back?

Comment: im doing a program where the user can view for unsorted list and then go back to main menu and choose second option to view for sorted list

Comment: and im thinking that deleting an item is also another problem for me if Im using the same list for sorted and unsorted

Comment: To maintain two sort orders you need to sets of links (head, tail, next, prev).

Comment: I guess you dont want to use Array because you want to add new item at head (linked list is better than array for this task). But another problem is you can not revert a list after sorting it. Therefor, you should not changed item's orders of the list, if you want show a sorted list, just create a copy version of the origin list and sort it.

Comment: @TaQuangTu i see, that's what i assuming too, thanks for clearing my doubts, i think i will just create two different list then